# Why am I getting a null value on insertion?

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, post

I have a react app that makes a post request to the following code.

```php
<?php
require_once('dbSURL.php');
$stm = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO urlshortener (longUrl, shortId, userIp, userCountry, userCity, userOS, userAgent, createDate) VALUES (:longUrl, :shortId, :userIp, :userCountry, :userCity, :userOS, :userAgent, :createDate)");
$stm->bindParam(':longUrl', $_POST['longUrl']);
$stm->bindParam(':shortId', $_POST['shortId']);
$stm->bindParam(':userIp', $_POST['userIp']);
$stm->bindParam(':userCountry', $_POST['userCountry']);
$stm->bindParam(':userCity', $_POST['userCity']);
$stm->bindParam(':userOS', $_POST['userOS']);
$stm->bindParam(':userAgent', $_POST['userAgent']);
$stm->bindParam(':createDate', $_POST['createDate']);



if ($stm->execute()) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failure: ".$stm->errorInfo()[2];
};
// $stm->execute();
// echo 'Error: %s.\n', $stm->errorCode(), $stm->errorInfo();
?>
```

After checking the request from dev tools I can see that the data are sent but when I get the data from the database all the fields are null.

Any help?

Comment: post request from react

Comment: You've verified that the data is sent already though, so that puts React out of the scope of the problem. Have you verified it on the server side? Such as logging the values of the `$_POST` values?

Comment: nope because I was sure since the code is copy paste from another project and just changed the values the db and the db table

Comment: and yes php returns them null

Comment: To clarify, something like `error_log($_POST['longURL']);` shows `null`?

Comment: yes it returns nothing

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide more details surrounding this code. Maybe include the request you're observing from the dev tools to show what parameters are being sent.